# Research databases

Tags: human-biology

So I'm just a lay person who likes to read about human biology/medical research but I dislike reading what so and so thinks of certain studies from pop articles. I like reading them for myself and I was just wondering which peer reviewed databases are the most reliable and accessable in your guys opinions?  I think researchgate is pretty good but I find navigating around the sign up inconvenient since you have to be working with a relevant company to join.  I hope I worded this specific enough thank you all who answer much appreciated!

Comment: Too much informality and opinion in the question for the forum ( i didn';t downvote as you have 1, other humans delight in downvoting cos their innately apathetic) ... I check https://scholar.google.fr/ and i check  "abstract" with the keywords in google search.

Comment: So post with more formality and less opinion next time?

Comment: Yes it's good to practice writing same as the articles that you like to read rather than the pop articles than you dislike reading :) when someone downvotes you you get -20 and fast you are restricted from the website.

Comment: Your title is confusing. Databases are a resource for research but not research, and are not peer reviewed as such. You are not asking about databases but scientific research. This is likely to be voted as off topic because opinions are subjective (I wouldn't recommend you follow the advice of tsttst if you are a lay person.) Is Scientific American or New Scientist what you are after? The News and Views section of Nature and the corresponding section of Science are also good. But you get what you pay for, and journalism costs.

Answer (score 2):

[Pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) is the major database for biomedical research articles. Especially if you know what you're looking for, it should be easy to find.

Google scholar will also compile things that are not peer-reviewed journal articles. Sometimes that's useful (e.g. PhD theses) but you will have to be a little careful.

Comment: . . . and if you create NCBI account, you can create alerts and get new papers about the topic of your interest delivered to your e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Google Scholar is good, since it searches all kinds of databases and gives you different options to view full articles.  If you use Mendeley and get Mendeley Desktop, you can import articles that you like and it will often suggest other articles you might like as well.  I know what you mean about the pop articles, they're often misleading ;)

Comment: I've known about Scholar for awhile and never checked it out till last night I only spent a couple  minutes on but it does seem pretty good. I've spent the last half hour on Mendeley on your recommend and I like it alot so far very organized and easy to use in my opinion thank you very much.